# Executing perl command from php

Tags: php, perl, system

I am suppose to replace a word in a text file using perl call from php page.

I tried following

```
`perl -pi -e 's/foo/bar/g' /tmp/newxml.xml`;

system('perl -pi -e \'s/foo/bar/g\' /tmp/newxml.xml', $retval1);

exec('perl -pi -e \'s/foo/bar/g\' /tmp/newxml.xml', $retval1, $retval2);
```

and its not working.

I tried follwoing

```
system('perl -v > /tmp/newxml.xml', $retval1);
```

and its working, hence I guess its not a permission issue.

I executed the command directly on shell and its working properly. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Could you explain what `is not working`, I tried it and everything's ok.

Comment: all of the commands are not able to replace the word in the specified file.

My future investigation showed that http or apache user is not a sudoer and hence not able to execute the given command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 system('perl -pi -e ''s/foo/bar/g'' /tmp/newxml.xml', $retval1);
```

or

```
system("perl -pi -e 's/foo/bar/g' /tmp/newxml.xml", $retval1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

`echo 'mypassword' | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --output outfile --decrypt inputfile`
```